# Wait for all the downstream tasks from the previous run in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am running multiple instances. So, `max_active_runs=1` is not a solution for me.
`wait_for_downstream` can wait only for the immediately downstream task.

From `baseoperator.py` code,

> wait_for_downstream: when set to true, an instance of task
> X will wait for tasks immediately downstream of the previous instance
> of task X to finish successfully before it runs. This is useful if the
> different instances of a task X alter the same asset, and this asset
> is used by tasks downstream of task X. Note that depends_on_past
> is forced to True wherever wait_for_downstream is used. Also note that
> only tasks *immediately* downstream of the previous task instance are waited
> for; the statuses of any tasks further downstream are ignored.

How to wait for all the downstream tasks?

There are multiple parallel steps in my DAG.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I tried ExternalTaskSensor as suggested by Relic16 to wait for C1/C2/C3 .. to get completed. It's creating a race condition during backfill. As there are multiple instances running at a time though `depends_on_past` is True. As soon as 1st run's ExternalTaskSensor is in SUCCESS and the actual next task(A1/A2/A3.. ) is processed, it triggers ExternalTaskSensor in the 2nd dag run and it consumers all the slots (as there are more than 16 parallel steps) and keep waiting for C1/C2/C3 .. to get completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume B, C and D are downstream tasks of A.
I can create a dummy task E which is downstream task for B, C and D.

Now I set an ExternalTaskSensor in A which waits for previous execution of task E to be finished.

For the very first run, I will mark the task successful manually but after that A will always wait for successful execution of task E from previous batch.

I can, using Trigger condition in E, further control dependency of  status of B, C and D on task E.

Comment: ExternalTaskSensor is creating a race condition during backfill. As there are multiple instances running at a time and depends_on_past is True. As soon as 1st run's ExternalTaskSensor is done and it move to the actual task, it triggers ExternalTaskSensor in the 2nd run and it consumers all the slots.

Comment: with `reschedule` mode in the ExternalTaskSensor, I am able to solve race condition.